# Excel Formula IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would really appreciate if you can help me on the excel formula logic. I am able to get the first part where I am able to display "1" in the check column if there is "Yes" in A,B,C columns and no values in either Amount 1, Amount 2 or Amount 3 columns  [(screenshot attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P584K.png)

I also want to display "1" if there in "No" is A,B,C columns and a value in either Amount1, Amount2 or Amount 3 columns.

`=IF(AND(E3="",F3="",G3="",OR(B3="Yes",C3="Yes",D3="Yes")),1,0)`

How to add the below formula to above one

```
or IF(AND(E3<>"",F3<>"",G3<>"",OR(B3="No",C3="No",D3="No")),1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(OR(AND(E3= "",F3= "",G3= "",OR(B3="Yes",C3="Yes",D3="Yes")), 
       AND(E3<>"",F3<>"",G3<>"",OR(B3="No" ,C3="No" ,D3="No" ))),1,0)
```